# TeamCity + Xcode 6 - Run Test action fails

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, continuous-integration, teamcity

I am trying to make a simple Xcode project work with TeamCity. Without running any tests I have succeeded.

I have a basic, Single View Application in Swift with one label on the screen. Both TeamCity (9.0.2) and Xcode (6.1.1) runs on the same machine (Mac mini) with an OS X (10.10.2) Server (4.0.3) installed on it. I have created a Git repository with Server and added as a remote to my sample Xcode project. After that, I've created successfully a working TeamCity project and build.

However when I try to check the **Run tests** checkmark the build WILL fail no matter what I do.

Configuration (dropbox image)
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55101816/Screen%20Shot%202015-03-01%20at%2002.45.48.png

Error message (and the messages right before that)

```
[02:31:48][FirstTeamCityProjectTests (BUILD)] Touch
[02:31:48][Touch] Touch build/Debug-iphoneos/FirstTeamCityProjectTests.xctest
[02:31:48][Touch]     cd /Library/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/55b27ad210b8fe77
[02:31:48][Touch]     export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/>    ontents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/bin:/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/sbin"
[02:31:48][Touch]     /usr/bin/touch -c /Library/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/55b27ad210b8fe77/build/Debug-iphoneos/FirstTeamCityProjectTests.xctest
[02:31:48][FirstTeamCityProjectTests (BUILD)] CodeSign
[02:31:48][CodeSign] CodeSign build/Debug-iphoneos/FirstTeamCityProjectTests.xctest
[02:31:48][CodeSign]     cd /Library/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/55b27ad210b8fe77
[02:31:48][CodeSign]     export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
[02:31:48][CodeSign]     export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/    Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/bin:/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/sbin"
[02:31:48][CodeSign] Signing Identity:     "iPhone Developer: *"
[02:31:48][CodeSign]     /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign * /Library/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/55b27ad210b8fe77/build/Debug-iphoneos/FirstTeamCityProjectTests.xctest
[02:31:48][Step 1/1] ** BUILD SUCCEEDED **
[02:31:48][Step 1/1] xcodebuild: error: Failed to build workspace FirstTeamCityProject with scheme FirstTeamCityProject.
[02:31:48][Step 1/1]    Reason: Xcode cannot run using the selected device.
[02:31:48][Step 1/1] Process exited with code 70
[02:31:48][Step 1/1] Step Xcode Project failed
```

Main problem I found with this error code and CI that they were trying with ssh and there were no GUI session. Currently I have a valid GUI session with the same user it uses, so it shouldn't be a problem.

The xcodebuild command is the following.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace FirstTeamCityProject.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace -scheme FirstTeamCityProject SYMROOT=/Library/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/55b27ad210b8fe77/build OBJROOT=/Library/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/55b27ad210b8fe77/build clean build test
```

What is missing here (I suppose) is one or more destinations.
I've executed the following command and it worked just fine. (Opened the Simulator, then exited with success.)

```
xcodebuild test -project FirstTeamCityProject.xcodeproj -scheme FirstTeamCityProject -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6,OS=8.1'
```

I seem to be alone with this problem, I didn't find any other relevant hits. Looking at this tutorial: http://pivotallabs.com/ios-continuous-deployment-teamcity-hockeyapp/, my issue should not be present at all.

**EDIT:**
The destination is indeed missing, but I don't understand why. Moreover if I try to add it manually the build fails. (I suspect that the order of the parameters matters, but how could I add this destination elsewhere in TeamCity.)

```
[01:48:12][Step 1/1] Building project: /Library/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/55b27ad210b8fe77/FirstTeamCityProject.xcodeproj
[01:48:12][Step 1/1] Using Xcode 6.1.1
[01:48:12][Step 1/1] Starting: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace FirstTeamCityProject.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace -scheme FirstTeamCityProject SYMROOT=/Library/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/55b27ad210b8fe77/build OBJROOT=/Library/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/55b27ad210b8fe77/build clean build test -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6,OS=8.1'
[01:48:12][Step 1/1] in directory: /Library/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/55b27ad210b8fe77
[01:48:12][Step 1/1] xcodebuild: error: option 'Destination' requires at least one parameter of the form 'key=value'
```

I appreciate any idea you have! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm confused.  You seem to have answered your own question in your question: "What is missing here ... is one or more destinations. I've executed the following command and it worked just fine." ... So what is the question?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with TeamCity, from what you wrote it definitely seems that the -destination flag is missing. If that helps here's the code of Bitrise.io's Xcode build step [disclaimer: CTO] which can run unit tests too: https://github.com/bitrise-io/steps-xcode-builder/blob/master/step.sh - you can give it a try on http://www.bitrise.io/ , we have an always free subscription plan.

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia Sorry for the confusion, I've just updated my question.

Answer (score 6):

in team city, when you configure the 'Xcode Project' build step,
add the destination parameter in the 'Additional command line parameters'
input box like so:

```
"-destination" "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6,OS=8.4"
```

**pay attention to the quotation marks**

that solved the issue for me (I checked it on TeamCity Professional 9.1.5 (build 37377)).

Comment: Worked for me, Thank you so much!

Comment: Worked here too - v 2017.1.3 (build 46961)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Well done TeamCity, spent like an hour trying to figure out the correct quotations marks.

Comment: Genius! Thanks for sharing. :)

Answer (score 4):

Please see [How to start TeamCity Build Agent on Mac OS on a user logon](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Setting+up+and+Running+Additional+Build+Agents#SettingupandRunningAdditionalBuildAgents-UsingLaunchDaemonsStartupFilesonMacOSx) to make it able to run the GUI applications (also see the note for Yosemite OS).

Comment: I tried the suggested workaround (and many variations of it), started the buildAgent (and everything) directly. Same error.

Comment: Though I had a kind of different problem this solved my issue. Basically the update to OSX 10.10 on our TeamCity buildagent had the effect that buildAgent could not interact the with the UI and thus not execute our unit tests. Doing the fix suggested for Yosemity in the above link did solve the problem :)

Comment: @farkasseb We found a bug in TeamCity before 9.0.4. We've updated the [Automatic Agent Start under MacOSx](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Setting+up+and+Running+Additional+Build+Agents#SettingupandRunningAdditionalBuildAgents-UsingLaunchDaemonsStartupFilesonMacOSx) section in documentation. Please try the suggested workaround.

Comment: @AlinaMishina Thank you! I could finally check on that solution you suggested. Now I am starting the buildAgent automatically as a LaunchAgent and it is working just fine.

Comment: @AlinaMishina However my other problem is still present. As JeremyHuddlestonSequoia pointed out a destination is missing. If I add
**-destination "platform=iOS Simulator,OS=8.3,name=iPhone 6"** to "Additional command line parameters" the build will succeed.

So it seems to me that TeamCity's Xcode Project plugin is missing the option to specify destinations after the "Run test" option is enabled.

Comment: Here is the related request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-23073 you can vote for.